# How to setup a new instance for load balancing in EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I posted this in stackoverflow but i dont know where it would be the best place for this.

Right now we have one instance. How do we create another instance with the content and files as the first server? Do we just create an instance?

Also if we make a change to a file on server one, do we have to make the same changes on server two? thanks

Comment: You'll usually want either some sort of shared storage - NFS, Amazon S3, Amazon Elastic File System, etc. - or a deployment method to deploy your code to all servers when you make a change. Shared storage is more important when you have things like user uploads.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading up on auto scaling groups.  This will teach you how to deploy an image that you can scale up or down as needed.  Keeping configurations stored somewhere that you can access during deployment is also helpful.  DynamoDB or S3 buckets can be locations for storing such configuration information.

Sorry that I can't give you a clear answer, your question allows for multiple solutions, done multiple ways.  I would recommend doing some reading first to see how you'd like to tackle your situation.

Answer (score 0):

As @Optichip said there are many answers to that question. A simpler one would be to make an *AMI* from your current instance (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html), then fire up another instance using your own *AMI*. In order to achieve greater resiliency, you should start this new instance on another *Availability Zone*.
Beware that creating an AMI out of a running instance will shut the instance in order to take a non-corrupted snapshot. It is actually possible to create that snapshot without shutting down the instance but it's really not recommended.
Once up, you will be able to create a `Elastic Load Balancer` to which you will attach both instances (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-deregister-register-instances.html).

In order to keep your datas in sync, there are a lot of options, the simplest would be to use the new *EFS* service which is basically an elastic NFS server, both of your servers would access the same files, stored on a shared network filesystem (https://aws.amazon.com/efs/).
Another solution would be to use a synchronisation software like `lsyncd` which is basically a daemon that syncs files between servers using rsync by looking at filesystem changes.